# Web Services com Axis2

Tags: java, web-service, axis2

Comecei estudar web services agora e esta dando esse erro

> This Web axisService has deployment faults

```
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException:  
org.apache.axis2.classloader.JarFileClassLoader cannot be cast to 
org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentClassLoader at 
org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceBuilder.populateService(ServiceBuilder.java:131) at 
org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.buildServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:101) at 
org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.processServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:178) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:82) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:661) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:337) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:241) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadServices(DeploymentEngine.java:131) at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.loadServices(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:284) at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:95) at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:567) at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:452) at org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet.init(AxisAdminServlet.java:56) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1213) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1026) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4425) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4738) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1060) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:822) at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1060) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:759) at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289) at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Está usando maven?

Comment: Veja se isso pode te ajudar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436631/webservice-with-eclipse-tomcat6-axis2-problem

Comment: Estou não, mas vou ver o link obrigado

Comment: storch
Pode nos dizer qual a configuração de sua aplicação:
IDE, Versão do Java-JDK, Servidor de aplicação (TOMCAT, JBoss, GlassFish) Uma dica: Usando Servidor de aplicação JBoss Wildfly, sua vida vai ficar muito mais facil ;-) O JBoss possui bibliotecas que para vc criar um webservice é só anotar a classe com @WebService e pronto, esta feito seu webservice. Mas caso queira usar o Axis descreva mais um pouco do seu projeto ai pra gente Vlw.